# how to handle the conflicts between Mybatis-Plus and Xstream

Tags: mybatis-plus

my project integrate Springcloud Eureka and Mybatis-plus but it can not work!

the exception when i boost the springcloud like this:

```
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'mapper' for bean class [com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.Mapper] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.mapper.Mapper]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:349) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathMapperScanner.java:310) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:287) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner.doScan(ClassPathMapperScanner.java:204) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.scan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:254) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(MapperScannerConfigurer.java:375) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at io.choerodon.mybatis.spring.CommonMapperScannerConfigurer.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(CommonMapperScannerConfigurer.java:79) ~[hzero-starter-mybatis-mapper-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:1.9.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:142) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.12.jar:2.5.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.5.12.jar:2.5.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:448) [spring-boot-2.5.12.jar:2.5.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) [spring-boot-2.5.12.jar:2.5.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1365) [spring-boot-2.5.12.jar:2.5.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) [spring-boot-2.5.12.jar:2.5.12]
    at com.anker.ipd.basis.IPDBasisApplication.main(IPDBasisApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
```

i try to find out what cause the conflict by `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Hi, `ConflictingBeanDefinitionException` occurs when there are multiple bean definitions with the same name but different classes. IMO the conflict is between the bean name 'mapper' defined in com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.Mapper and the existing bean definition with the same name but a different class com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.mapper.Mapper. Can you check this?

Comment: yes, i confirmed

Comment: Precisely,  com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.Mapper is a class within SpringCloud Eureka, so change the bean name from the bottom up is infeasible i think....